# Use SSH to auth jenkins CLI with unix auth

Tags: jenkins

I've setup jenkins to use unix auth, with works just fine with passwords. Is it possible to use ssh auth for the cli too? ssh `jenkins@localhost` works just fine, but `java -jar /opt/jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 who-am-i` fails (displays anonymous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the pubkey manually to `https://jenkins/user/$USER/configure`. Which only exists if you log in with said user first.